# ORACLE DB exp with FULL=y option cannot export all user tables but expdp can

Tags: oracle, expdp

I am trying to use the exp tool to backup the whole DB.

The command is "exp userid=system/manager@test inctype=complete buffer=65535 file=/home/oracle/backup/exp_full.dmp log=/home/oracle/backup/exp_full.log  full=y".

But from the exp log, it can only export some user tables, not all, even though those tables cannot exported indeed have content. Only these users can be exported from the log as below:

> . about to export SYSTEM's tables via Conventional Path ...
>
> . about to export OUTLN's tables via Conventional Path ...
>
> . about to export ORDDATA's tables via Conventional Path ...
>
> . about to export OLAPSYS's tables via Conventional Path ...

etc.

But when I try to use expdp with command `expdp system/manager dumpfile=expdp_full.dmp logfile=expdp_full.log full=y`, it can export all user tables successfully.

The ORACLE DB version is 11.2.0.1.0.
Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Why not use RMAN for backups?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify which schema you want to export , by expdp user/password schema=abc dumpfile=abc.dmp logfile=abc.log directory=abcdirectory

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Database Online Documentation Library, 11g Release 2 (11.2)](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle%2011%20original%20exp&oq=oracle%2011%20original%20exp%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.16047j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> Original Export is desupported for general use as of Oracle Database
> 11g. The only supported use of original Export in Oracle Database 11g
> is backward migration of XMLType data to Oracle Database 10g release 2
> (10.2) or earlier. Therefore, Oracle recommends that you use the new
> Data Pump Export and Import utilities, except in the following
> situations which require original Export and Import: You want to
> import files that were created using the original Export utility
> (exp).
>
> You want to export files that will be imported using the original
> Import utility (imp). An example of this would be if you wanted to
> export data from Oracle Database 10g and then import it into an
> earlier database release.